# Crystal Reports 2008 formula detail data

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Crystal Reports 2008 formula question here. Any help would be appreciated.

I need to pull records for a report that have two records in a detail table where conditions are met in the parent table. So if the parent table has box a and box b checked, I need to only pull detail info that has a 305 AND a 307 inspection. I can't do an `AND` though because the inspections are different records and it doesn't pull anything (i.e. there is no type that is both of them) I was thinking to loop thru and set a flag but that seems complicated.  I tried using the `xor`, `imp`, and `eqv` but those pull every other inspection type.

Here is my code:

```
({parent.box a} = "Y" and {parent.box b} = "Y" and ({insp.INSPTYPE} ="305" and {insp.INSPTYPE} ="307") and {insp.RESULT} ="PASSED"
```

Comment: Are insptype and box are related?

Comment: They are in different tables...but they are related in the fact that if boxa is checked inpstype must be 305, if boxb is checked insptype must be 307.  That part I can code for.  The hard part if when BOTH boxa and b are checked, I the inps table needs to have a record for both 305 and 307 (out of a lot of insp records).  How do you code for that?  Parenthesis do not work :-(  Thanks!

Comment: Thinking out of the box, what if you create an alias of the table, such that you have 2 table (with diff names) and join one 305 and other on 307. That way you wont have intersecting data they will be unique. Just a suggestin